# How to use regex in foreignkey in mogodb lookup

Tags: mongodb, lookup

How can I do a $lookup using wildcard on the foreign key field?

The task is to retrieve all records from **Transaction** where the the *desc* substring is *not* found in the **Keyword** collection.

The *desc* in Transaction could come in the form of abc<keyword>def, and cross referencing to **Keyword** collection, this should be a match if  is found.

I thought of using a negative match for regex `.*XXX.*` to achieve the task.

Not sure how to put a regex clause in a $lookup.

**Transaction** collection:

```
transactions=[
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6480267ab9fe78e82131b737"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": "2020-06-22T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "desc": "abcKey1def",
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6480267ab9fe78e82131b738"
  },
  "date": {
    "$date": "2020-06-23T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "desc": "abcdef",
}
]
```

**Keyword** collection:

```
keyword=[
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64816f3828372d84a93cd4ad"
  },
  "code": 123,
  "desc": "Key1"
},
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "648174bf28372d84a93cd4b5"
  },
  "code": 456,
  "desc": "Key2",
}
]
```

I know I probably need to use *let* and *pipeline*... but not sure how to put them together.

```
$lookup:{
  from: "keyword",
  let: {
    desc:'$desc'
  },
  pipeline: [
     ....?
  ]
  
  as: "result"
}
```

Comment: Can you add the expected output as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `$regexMatch` in `$lookup`. Like this:

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "keyword",
      "let": {
        desc: "$desc"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              "$regexMatch": {
                "input": "$$desc",
                "regex": {
                  "$concat": [
                    ".*",
                    "$desc",
                    ".*"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "matchingDocs"
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      matchingDocs: []
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JFgK3q_6Z2J)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the key as a variable and then join the keywords using the key.
I am extracting the key here, under the assumption that it will always be abcdef. At the end it filter out records which does not have matching keywords.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/B0SIHY68gz0

```
db.transactions.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "keywords",
      let: {
        keywordStr: {
          $substr: [
            "$desc",
            3,
            {
              $subtract: [
                {
                  $strLenCP: "$desc"
                },
                6
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$desc",
                "$$keywordStr"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "keywords"
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      keywords: {
        $ne: []
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.Transaction.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "Keyword",
      let: { keywordSubstring: { $regexFind: { input: "$desc", regex: "<keyword>", options: "i" } } },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $not: {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$keywordSubstring.match",
                  regex: { $concat: [".*", { $escapeRegex: "$$keywordSubstring.match" }, ".*"] },
                  options: "i"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "keywordMatches"
    }
  }
])
```